# Bootstrap modal closes on enter with runat server textarea

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am developing a page in asp.net. I have a Bootstrap modal with a form in it. The form within the bootstrap modal has a textbox and a textarea.
[bootstrapModalView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0KOq.png).
 I am using javascript to add each vin# from textbox into the vin list textarea on enter press.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //In "Scan VINs," add VIN# to VIN List
    $('#modalForm').on("keypress", function (e) {
        //If "enter/return" is pressed, put vin# into vin list textarea
        if (e.which == 13) {
            enterModalTxtVIN();
            return false;
        }
    });

    //Hide invalidVIN div until error occurs
    document.getElementById('invalidVIN').style.display = 'none';
});

//(On Modal) After clicking "enter" on VIN# textbox, VIN# goes into VIN List text area
function enterModalTxtVIN() {
    var text = document.getElementById('modalTxtVIN').value;

    //If modalTxtVIN length does not = 17 characters, inform user incorrect length and cancel
    if (text.length != 17) {
        //Show error
        document.getElementById('invalidVIN').style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    } else {
        //Hide error
        document.getElementById('invalidVIN').style.display = 'none';

        //Add vin# to vin list text area
        document.getElementById('modalTxtAreaVINList').value += text.toUpperCase() + "\n";
        document.getElementById('modalTxtVIN').value = "";
    }
}
```

That works great and fine, but I need to access the textarea in the code behind. So I added a runat=server to my textarea.

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="modalTxtAreaVINList" name="modalTxtAreaVINList" runat="server" readonly ></textarea>
```

But when I add that runat=server, this line of javascript that accesses the textarea closes the modal when I click enter now.

```
document.getElementById('modalTxtAreaVINList').value += text.toUpperCase() + "\n";
```

How can I either make the modal not close with the runat=server there, or how do I access the data from the codebehind without the runat=server?

Comment: As a workaround, you could add the same data also to a hidden field separated by a comma and read that on server, then remove the runat from the textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've added `runat=server`, the id of your textarea as visible from JavaScript will not be `modalTxtAreaVINList` any more. When  ASP.NET processes the .aspx/.ascx files to produce the HTML, it will generate new IDs for the server-side controls, *ClientIDs*. So `document.getElementById` will not find your textbox.

Two solutions:

1) Print the 'real' id, that is the one that actually appears inside the HTML, inside a JavaScript code using `<%= modalTxtAreaVINList.ClientID %>`, for example

```
document.getElementById('<%= modalTxtAreaVINList.ClientID %>')
```

2) Or, add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the textarea, to force ASP.NET to output the same ID as you typed in.

Comment: The first solution didn't work the way I needed. But the 2nd solution worked perfect for me. Thanks a lot!